# header of php not redirecting to mention page

Tags: php, networking, redirect, header

I'm using header function of php to redirect to index page , but after redirect, an error has been com out that you are not connected to network.

both file are in same directory.

code is

```
function chklogin()
{
  require('script/session.php');
  if(isset($usernmae))
     {   
      echo "welcome";
     }
     else
     { 
      header('location: index.php');
     }
 }
header('location: index.php');
```

Comment: I don't have a copy of your code on my system. Maybe posting it would be great.

Comment: Huh? Can you please explain it more? Happens only on index.php?

Comment: No where near enough information here. Is $username even in scope? It's not even spelled right.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this please and then try :)

```
function chklogin()
{
  require('script/session.php');
  if(isset($username))
     {   
      echo "welcome ".$username;
     }
     else
     { 
      header('Location: /index.php');
     }
}
chklogin();
```